Power BI DAX Switch returning blank values
    I have a table - RaceTopMeasure
A calculated column has the following DAX. It uses the Switch function to select which column in a related table - Runner - to use when determining the minimum, I want to find the RunnerID with the lowest value in column MinZAVG800 when RaceID - 1. Each RaceID has 4 rows in table RaceTOpMeasure. For each of the 4 rows I want column 3 to return the runnerID with the Min Value in the Column specified in the switch.
At the moment it compiles without errors but returns nothing Column names match. The values in table runner are themselves DAX expressions
Many Thanks
Column3 =
VAR RaceIDValue = RaceTopMeasure[RaceID]
VAR ColumnNameValue =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( RaceTopMeasure[The Measure] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MINX (
            FILTER ( 'Runner', 'Runner'[RaceID] = RaceIDValue ),
            SWITCH (
                TRUE (),
                ColumnNameValue = "MinZAVG800", 'Runner'[MinZAVG800],
                ColumnNameValue = "SumZAVG800", 'Runner'[SumZAVG800],
                ColumnNameValue = "MinZAVG800ZActual", 'Runner'[MinZAVG800ZActual],
                ColumnNameValue = "SumZAVG800ZActual", 'Runner'[SumZAVG800ZActual]
            )
        ),
        'Runner'[RaceID] = RaceIDValue
    )


I tried the DAX shown and was expected a Value for RunnerID with the lowest value in the column specified to be returned.But nothing is returned
